# How to generate a download link from Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

files from the google.docs generally open in view mode. But after some additions in link, we can change the link to direct download.

I have given a docs link below . How can I turn it into a download link?
https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxoaWprbG1uMjN8Z3g6MjY2NWMxNjM1ZWYxNWNmYQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.
Click on print Icon on the top-left, it will pop up printing controls on the left, then if you press ctrl+s , you can save it as PDF format. And also, this is not a good question for this site:)

EDIT
From [here](http://thebiobucket.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-link-to-google-docs-for-download.html)

How to Link to Files at Google Docs for Direct Download
...Google doesn't tell you this, as far as I know - so, if you want to link to a file at Google Docs for direct download you can use the following address scheme:

```
https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=YourIndividualID
```

You can copy your individual file id from within the "Share..."-dialogue. Here you also need to put the share settings to "public" or to "anyone with the link"

a HTML example for this link to a pdf-file:

```
<a href="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B2wAunwURQNsNWU1NjcyOGMtYWI0Ni00MzQ5LTg3ZTAtOTc5ZjUwMmZiZDMy">
</a>
```

Online generating tool [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gdocs2direct/).

Comment: No, sir! I want to give the file in the downloads page of my website. So, im searching for the code to direct download.

Comment: You can upload that file to your server, for example `/home/files/my_file.pdf` and add that link from your site:)

Comment: what code ? in what language ? please be more concrete

Comment: :-) There is a way to change the link from view mode to direct download.

Comment: I think I got what you need, I have edited my answer :)

Comment: Exactly. u did what i want. But i couldn't change the link given in my question for direct downloading.

Comment: How have you tried to do ?

Comment: <a href="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxoaWprbG1uMjN8Z3g6MjY2NWMxNjM1ZWYxNWNmYQ">Click here to download</a> is not working. Why?

Comment: you have error in your link, look at it again, there is something like this at the end of the link 
>Click , watch it again

Comment: Could you Please make a download link from the google.docs file in my question.

Comment: I have downloaded that file, than uploaded in my Google Drive, and then with the method I mentioned I made that link, here is it
[link](https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BymYr3wSOPfceThrWnU3SUV5c1k)  or this, the same
`https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BymYr3wSOPfceThrWnU3SUV5c1k`  . And don't remember to mark the question as answered :)

Comment: Ok sir. Thanks for the time spent for me and thanks for your kind heart.

Comment: :)And don't remember to mark the question as answered :)

Comment: This works for Drive, but I do not believe it works for Docs